# OpenVPN Connection on startup (Windows) only if not at home

Tags: windows, cmd, vpn, startup, openvpn

I want my OpenVPN to automatically connect on startup, but only if I am not at home. With some help of this community I was able to put together a batch script, that is supposed to do so, but it keeps throwing the error "-connect" could not be parsed as an argument because no "--" could be found, but there is a "--". Where is my mistake?

```
@echo off
set "SSID=Home_Network_SSID"
(netsh wlan show networks mode=ssid | findstr /C:"%SSID%" >nul 2>&1)&&goto :Home
echo "Nicht zu Hause, VPN wird verbunden...
start "OpenVPN" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect profile.ovpn
timeout /T 5
echo "VPN wurde gestartet"
goto :end

:Home
echo "Heimnetzwerk erkannt, VPN wird nicht verbunden."
timeout /T 5
goto :end
```

In addition, it also fires the query to the client if I am at home, so it does not really work.
If I put

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe --connect profile.ovpn"
```

directly into cmd,  there is no problem.

Please do not wonder about the german echos.
Thank you very much,

DarkDiamond

Comment: it should probably be `findstr /C:"%SSID%"`. Yours has a big problem with spaces in the variable.

Comment: I would suggest using  `Start "OpenVPN" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect profile.ovpn`. _This assumes that `profile.ovpn` is in the current directory, or a location normally parsed by `openvpn-gui.exe`, otherwise, you may need to provide a `/D` option and parameter to `Start`. (You may not even need to use `Start` at all BTW, `"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect profile.ovpn`, or the `timeout` which follows it.)_

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. I will change my code in the post, so it is how it is now.

Comment: run with `@echo off` and `>nul 2>&1` removed, and examine (and/or share) the output.

Comment: @Stephan I did so, the problem is that there is personal information in there, so I will not publish it in the original way but alter it a bit, I hope it is still helpful:
`
C:\Users\My_Name\Documents>set "SSID=My_SSID"

C:\Users\My_Name\Documents>(netsh wlan show networks mode=ssid   | findstr /C:"My_SSID" )  && goto :Home
SSID 2 : My_SSID Guest_Network
SSID 3 : My_SSID

C:\Users\My_Name\Documents>echo "Heimnetzwerk erkannt, VPN wird nicht verbunden."
"Heimnetzwerk erkannt, VPN wird nicht verbunden."

C:\Users\My_Name\Documents>timeout /T 50
`
Sorry but it doesn't format properly

Comment: ok, that looks good so far (with your home network). What about "not-at-home"? (no reason to leave home, just `set "SSID=Not_My_SSID"` to simulate)

Comment: @Stephan It opens the connection dialog, just as I want it to do. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Now, 30 seconds later, it again displays the error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did even more research on this topic, and found something very useful that I use now instead of my own little batch file as it does what I want it to do, and that always when I connect to a wifi, and does not only check on startup. Using this task from within the windows task scheduler, it runs in the background, and I never had to think about it since I configured it.

[These](https://gist.github.com/carlin-q-scott/77cbb064c3c2e332af011714fb2aa585) 2 xml files have to be edited exactly how the installation instructions describe it, and then it works just fine for my needs. There is also the possibility to disable all popups, but in order for this to work, you need your password for the OpenVPN connection to be stored in plain text next to the config file, which I don't want to do. If you do this, you have to be very careful, whoever gets his hand on both of these files will be able to connect to your vpn server (which is probably in your home LAN behind all firewalls!) with your credentials and thus can steal data or even place viruses throughout the network. Considering this, I would definitely not recommend to use this option and rather type in the password manually every time the laptop connects to a different wifi than your home's.

Also the second task, which handles the disconnection whenever your disconnect from a wifi works well. It just kills every task with "openvpn" in it's name, so you are good to go for the next connection.

I did not figure this out by myself, all credits go to [Carlin Scott](https://gist.github.com/carlin-q-scott) who wrote the tasks. I just wanted to share my results with you as you helped me very much with the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, I found that the problem was the "Task Scheduler". So, no problem after the fix, but this is not important for this question.

---

### Here the solution to the raised question:

```
@echo off
set "SSID=Home_Network_SSID"
(netsh wlan show networks mode=ssid | findstr /C:"%SSID%")&&goto :Home
echo Not at home, starting VPN...
start "OpenVPN" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect profile.ovpn
timeout /T 5
echo VPN has been started.
goto :end

:Home
echo Home network detected, VPN will not be connected.
timeout /T 5
goto :end

:end
```

In order for this to work, your `profile.ovpn` needs to be in a directory that is scanned by the OpenVPN client, either your personal folder
`C:\Users\Your_Name\OpenVPN\config\Some_Folder` or the common folder `C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config`

The last thing you need to do is to put a link to the .bat-file you put this code in into the startup directory. You find this by pressing WIN+R and entering `shell:startup`.

---

Feel free to use this, I hope I can help all those people who want to have this function but are not used to programming as I was before this.

Comment: so the error actually was that it couldn't find `profile.ovpn`? Wow - that was a really misleading error message!